# C++ Pattern for Test endless loop called from thread

Tags: c++, linux, unit-testing, c++11, catch2

How i can to test with Catch2 an endless loop called from a thread. e.g:

```
static vector<some_type> v; //vector with results
class foo
{
   public:
   foo(<many arguments>){}

   void endless_loop()
   {
      while(true)
      {
        //long process
        //....
        v.push_back(result_process);
      }
   }

   void bar()
   {
     thread(foo);
   }
};
```

In this case how test foo class, bar and endless_loop method? Exist any test pattern for this case?

Thanks!

Comment: What do they do? How do you use them in real code? What can you change?

Comment: ideally I shouldn't change anything. In the real code i should call bar function for start the endless loop and look in the vector for results.

Comment: Why not do the same in test?

Comment: Because if I change the source code I would have to change it in the test too